# Fake UTC timestamp to display time on any client in some given locale

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

I've got a black-magic question about timezones.

I have an application where I need timestamped event. I store everything in UTC. However, I want to display (client-side) the date, neither in the user locale nor in UTC, but in a given timezone (namely, the Paris timezone).

Since there is no javascript way to do it easily (we would have to know the exact daylight saving time events using something like timezone.js which seems overkill), I wanted to do the following trick:

- get the UTC date `dutc=datetime(…,<UTC>)`
- convert it to paris date `dparis=datetime(…,<Paris>)`
- force the tzinfo back to UTC to get an UTC timestamp corresponding to the date & time in Paris (eg. the same numerical date & time, but with UTC rather than Paris, without adding or removing hours)
- storing this UTC date as a timestamp so the client could parse it as a "fake UTC " timestamp, and display the "fake time  "

However, I don't get back my original timestamp

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz
utc = pytz.UTC
paris = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
t = 1372982409 # timestamp in UTC

dutc = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t, utc) # date in UTC
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)

dparis = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t, paris) # date in Paris time
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 2, 0, 9, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:0
0:00 DST>)

dparisasutc = dparis.replace(tzinfo=utc) # force the date in UTC time
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 2, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)

t0 = time.mktime(dparisasutc.timetuple())
# 1372986009.0

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t0)
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9) # why not 02:00:09?
```

Comment: And what is your local timezone when you run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to:

> - get the UTC date dutc=datetime(…,)
> - convert it to paris date dparis=datetime(…,)

Ok, I'm with you so far, but then...

> - force the tzinfo back to UTC to get an UTC timestamp corresponding to the date & time in Paris (eg. the same numerical date & time, but with UTC rather than Paris, without adding or removing hours)
> - storing this UTC date as a timestamp so the client could parse it as a "fake UTC " timestamp, and display the "fake time "

This might be a bad idea.  The general convention is that at timestamp represented as an integer is always based on UTC.  This holds true *almost* everywhere (with certain Microsoft .Net types being the exception).

Since you're client is in JavaScript, they would expect any integer to be the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.  Changing that will have some strange consequences.  The most interesting one is that you will get the user's own local time zone's rules about daylight saving time to be applied erroneously.  These can be excruciatingly difficult to find in testing.

The simplest answer to to not use the `Date` type in JavaScript at all.  Do the conversion to Paris time completely on the server, and pass a well-formatted string back to the browser.

A more interesting solution would be to pass the UTC time, either in an integer or as an ISO8601 string like `2013-08-21T17:29:00Z`.  On the client, use a library that can recognize the UTC time and convert it to the `Europe/Paris` zone.  You mentioned not wanting to do this using timezone.js, but there are [several other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) to choose from.  Some are very small, and let you include just the date for the zones you care about.

For example, try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) addon.  You can specifically build a moment-timezone-data.js file containing only the `Europe/Paris` zone data.  (They have a nice interactive data builder on that site for this.)

Comment: That's what I finally did actually

Comment: out of curiosity, which suggestion did you go with?  The simple string solution? Or moment-timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Use the timezone's `.localize()` method to apply a timezone other than UTC to a timestamp:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> import pytz
>>> utc = pytz.UTC
>>> paris = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
>>> t = 1372982409 # timestamp in UTC
>>> dparis = paris.localize(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t))
>>> dparis
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 1, 0, 9, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Note the *one hour* time difference now displayed, as the correct *current* and not historical timezone transitions are applied.

Next, you need to interpret the resulting timestamp as UTC again lest Python apply the local timezone to the timestamp again:

```
>>> dparisasutc = dparis.replace(tzinfo=utc) # force the date in UTC time
>>> dparisasutc
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 1, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> t0 = time.mktime(dparisasutc.timetuple())
>>> t0
1372986009.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t0, utc)
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 1, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: What do you mean by current vs historical timezone transition? I think what I'm looking for is the historical timezone transition, eg. I want to know what hour it was in Paris at that precise UTC time. What is the difference between both approaches, what does localize do with the current timezone? BTW the current daylight saving time is the same for both the date I'm looking at & today http://24timezones.com/world_directory/current_paris_time.php

Answer (score 1):

Because `time.mktime` returns `struct_time` in **local time**. You should read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and use `calendar.timegm()` instead which returns `struct_time` in **UTC**.

This is an old thing that remained from ancient times unfortunately. And never got changed because it could brake people code :(

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz
import calendar
utc = pytz.UTC
paris = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
t = 1372982409 # timestamp in UTC

dutc = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t, utc) # date in UTC
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)

dparis = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t, paris) # date in Paris time
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 2, 0, 9, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

dparisasutc = dparis.replace(tzinfo=utc) # force the date in UTC time
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 2, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>)    

t0 = calendar.timegm(dparis.timetuple())
print t0
# 1372989609.0

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t0, utc)
# datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 2, 0, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>) # now it is 02:00:09
```